# laravel check first part of URL e.g. domain.com/THIS-PART

Tags: php, url, laravel, uri

I currently do a check for pages that are simple e.g. /profile /index etc.

However I have a page which is:

```
domain.com/viewbuild/105/a-title
```

which equates to:

```
domain.com/viewbuild.php?id=105&name=a-title
```

My current check is:

```
$sUri = Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri();
if ($sUri == '/' || $sUri == 'viewbuild' || $sUri == 'newest')
{
// is on URL
}
```

This works for the other URLs, but not for the viewbuild. How can I detect for this URL but not the variables since its dynamic.

Thanks.

Comment: And the value of `$sUri` is what in case you can't detect it?

Comment: Havent come across that issue yet... :/ Ill make a fix for that so it defaults to '/' :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `segment()` function:

```
$sUri = Request::segment(1);
if ($sUri == '/' || $sUri == 'viewbuild' || $sUri == 'newest')
{
    // is on URL
}
```

Comment: Has this question been answered? If so - can you please accept it - or provide more info